# Vuelidate validate a bootstrapvue / vue form field on click action

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vuelidate, vue-validator

I'm creating a signup form which verifies if a login_id selected by the user is available on the server. 
This form is on **bootstrapvue**.

```
     <b-form @submit="onSubmit" v-if="show" @reset="onReset" >
      <b-form-group
        id="signupInputGroup0"
        label="Login:"
        label-for="exampleInput0"
        description="Choose a unique login id"
        valid-feedback="Great! Your login id is unique"
        invalid-feedback="Login id already exists. Please pick another login.">
        <b-form-input
          id="signupInput0"
          type="login"
          v-model="form.login"
          required
          placeholder="Enter a unique login id" 
          />
        <b-button variant="success" @click="onCheckAvailability">Check Availability</b-button>
      </b-form-group>
     ...
```

My question now is regarding the call to **onCheckAvailability**. This function is going to call an API and set the valid status to **LoginId** field.

Am actually considering **vuelidate** to create validations for all form fields. Customize my own validation method call ***isUniqueLogin***

```
   validations:{
    form: {
      login: {
        required,
        isUniqueLogin: this.onCheckAvailability(this.login) 
      }, ...
```

In such a case, how do we pass this **validation on click** back to the form? 
I'm looking for a neat and elegant way of doing it. 
And also OK to use something else that can do this well.

***Note:*** This is not a submit click. It's a simple field validation on click. 
Sometimes, using frameworks can be tedious if I don't understand the paradigms well.

Comment: `<b-form-input>` does not have props for `invalid-feedback` or `valid-feedback`.  Those props are on the `<b-form-group>`

Comment: That's a wrong use. Will correct it. Also, I'm giving a try at state prop now. Very helpful @TroyMorehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `<b-form-group>` and `<b-form-input>` have a prop called `state` which accepts `true` if the value is valid, `false` for invalid, or `null` if not validated.

You would need to set this prop (on both `<b-form-group>` and `<b-form-input>`) to the result of the `checkAvailability` call.

Note that `invalid-feedback` and `valid-feedback` props are used on `<b-form-group>` not `<b-form-input>`

See https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-group